# Laravel Feature Testing

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

I am new to unit and feature testing in Laravel but want to create some feature tests on my Incident Controller. When trying to run these tests, I am getting the following:

##### IncidentController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Incident;

class IncidentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $incidents = Incident::latest()->paginate(5);

        //return view('incident.index');
        return view('incident.index',compact('incidents'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //return view('createIncident.blade.php');
        return view('incident.create');
        //return view('incident.edit',compact('incident'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'assigned_to' => 'required',
            'completed_status' => 'required',
        ]);

        Incident::create($request->all());
 
        return redirect()->route('incidents.index')
                    ->with('success','Incident created successfully.');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Incident $incident)
    {
        return view('incident.show',compact('incident'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Incident $incident)
    {
        return view('incident.edit',compact('incident'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Incident $incident)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'assigned_to' => 'required',
            'completed' => 'required',
        ]);

        $incident->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('incidents.index')
                    ->with('success','Incident updated successfully');
    }

    /**
    * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Incident $incident)
    {
        $incident->delete();

        return redirect()->route('incidents.index')
                    ->with('success','Incident deleted successfully');
    }
}
```

##### IncidentTest

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Models\Incident;

class IncidentTest extends TestCase
{
    // use RefreshDatabase;

    /**
     * Test the index method to ensure incidents are displayed correctly.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testIndex()
    {
        // Create some incidents in the database
        Incident::factory()->count(10)->create();

        // Send a GET request to the index route
        $response = $this->get(route('incidents.index'));

        // Assert that the response has a successful status code
        $response->assertOk();

        // Assert that the incidents are displayed on the page
        $response->assertViewHas('incidents');
    }

    /**
     * Test the store method to ensure incidents can be created successfully.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testStore()
    {
        // Send a POST request to the store route with valid incident data
        $response = $this->post(route('incidents.store'), [
            'name' => 'Test Incident',
            'description' => 'This is a test incident',
            'assigned_to' => 'User',
            'completed_status' => 'open',
        ]);

        // Assert that the incident was created in the database
        $this->assertDatabaseHas('incidents', [
            'name' => 'Test Incident',
            'description' => 'This is a test incident',
            'assigned_to' => 'User',
            'completed_status' => 'open',
        ]);

        // Assert that the user is redirected to the index route
        $response->assertRedirect(route('incidents.index'));
    }

    /**
     * Test the update method to ensure incidents can be updated successfully.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testUpdate()
    {
        // Create an incident in the database
        $incident = Incident::factory()->create();

        // Send a PUT request to the update route with updated incident data
        $response = $this->put(route('incidents.edit', $incident->id), [
            'name' => 'Updated Incident',
            'description' => 'This is an updated incident',
            'assigned_to' => 'Admin',
            'completed_status' => 'open',
       ]);

        // Assert that the incident was updated in the database
        $this->assertDatabaseHas('incidents', [
            'id' => $incident->id,
            'name' => 'Updated Incident',
            'description' => 'This is an updated incident',
            'assigned_to' => 'Admin',
            'completed_status' => 'open',
        ]);

        // Assert that the user is redirected to the index route
        $response->assertRedirect(route('incident.index'));
    }

    /**
     * Test the destroy method to ensure incidents can be deleted successfully.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testDestroy()
    {
        // Create an incident in the database
        $incident = Incident::factory()->create();

        // Send a DELETE request to the destroy route
        $response = $this->delete(route('incidents.destroy', $incident->id));

        // Assert that the incident was deleted from the database
        $this->assertDatabaseMissing('incidents', [
            'id' => $incident->id,
        ]);

        // Assert that the user is redirected to the index route
        $response->assertRedirect(route('incident.index'));
    }
}
```

##### Errors received

```bash
C:\wamp64\www\IncidentManagement\incident_management\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:107
      PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()

  • Tests\Feature\IncidentTest > store
  Failed asserting that a row in the table [incidents] matches the attributes {
      "name": "Test Incident",
      "description": "This is a test incident",
      "assigned_to": "User",
      "completed_status": "open"
  }.
  
  Found: [
      {
          "id": 29,
          "name": "INC1111111",
          "description": "PHPUnit Test",
          "assigned_to": "Admin",
          "completed_status": "open",
          "created_at": "2023-06-06 10:57:55",
          "updated_at": "2023-06-06 10:57:55"
      }
  ].

  at C:\wamp64\www\IncidentManagement\incident_management\tests\Feature\IncidentTest.php:57
     53▕         //]);
     54▕
     55▕         // Assert that the incident was created in the database
     56▕         $this->assertDatabaseHas('incidents', [
  ➜  57▕             'name' => 'Test Incident',
     58▕             'description' => 'This is a test incident',
     59▕             'assigned_to' => 'User',
     60▕             'completed_status' => 'open',
     61▕         ]);

  1   C:\wamp64\www\IncidentManagement\incident_management\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:107
      PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()

  • Tests\Feature\IncidentTest > update
   PHPUnit\Framework\ExceptionWrapper 

  Call to undefined method App\Models\Incident::factory()

  at C:\wamp64\www\IncidentManagement\incident_management\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php:71
     67▕      * @throws \BadMethodCallException
     68▕      */
     69▕     protected static function throwBadMethodCallException($method)
     70▕     {
  ➜  71▕         throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
     72▕             'Call to undefined method %s::%s()', static::class, $method
     73▕         ));
     74▕     }
     75▕ }

  1   C:\wamp64\www\IncidentManagement\incident_management\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:107
      PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()

  • Tests\Feature\IncidentTest > destroy
   PHPUnit\Framework\ExceptionWrapper 

  Call to undefined method App\Models\Incident::factory()

  at C:\wamp64\www\IncidentManagement\incident_management\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php:71
     67▕      * @throws \BadMethodCallException
     68▕      */
     69▕     protected static function throwBadMethodCallException($method)
     70▕     {
  ➜  71▕         throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
     72▕             'Call to undefined method %s::%s()', static::class, $method
     73▕         ));
     74▕     }
     75▕ }

  1   C:\wamp64\www\IncidentManagement\incident_management\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:107
      PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
```

Does anyone know how I would be able to resolve this, please?

I am expecting that the test will create a new incident in the database, update it and then delete it, showing that it will have passed for all CRUD actions.

Comment: try using `dd($request->all())` after the `$request->validate()` in store method to check if the data is sent correctly

Comment: Your controller and test look fine to me. The PHPUnit response is just dumping the first record in the table because it didn't find any matching results, so I think the advice to run `dd($request->all())` may help. It would also help to see the Incident model. I think that may be missing as `use HasFactory;` which could cause the failures of the later tests?

Comment: I am not exactly sure, but enable `RefreshDatabase` again, I do not know why you have it commented out

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).